# How using ROM BIOS interrupts in borland c++ 5.02?

Tags: c++

I am using Borland C++ 5.02 and I was trying to make ROM BIOS interrupts in a c++ program. (i use REGS & regs). But when I compile the program it says undefined structure REGS(for all interrupts).

```
int numlock() {
    union REGS in,out;
    in.h.ah=2;
    int86(0x16,&in,&out);
    return out.h.al;
}
union REGS in,out;  //**error line**
```

Comment: This is a problem in Borland 5.2. is Better for use interrupts ,working with Borland 4.5. I used Borland 4.5 & answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem in Borland 5.2. is Better for use interrupts ,working with Borland 4.5. I used Borland 4.5 & answered.